# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing for Opera

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, opera, cors

Has anybody found a workaround for Opera regarding Cross-Origin Resource Sharing?

I want to make a cross domain `XmlHttpRequest` to my domain foo.com from my script placed on bar.com.

The [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) so far is not implemented by Opera.

Examples and documentation on how to do this on other browsers can be found [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

As far as I tested, you can do this on Firefox, IE, Safari and Chrome. But not on Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible alternative is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross domain requests.

Answer (score 3):

JSONP is the best/only way to get basic CORS functionality (only GET, as it uses a `<script>` tag internally) if the browser doesn't support real CORS.

Comment: You could also do server-side proxying

Comment: But it's not good for Opera, <script> while loading blocks all other <script>s execution...

Comment: For post request you can use ajax+php curl. Lot of tutorial are available you can use "ajax php curl cross domain post" keyword to search in google .

Comment: That's not really considered a cross-origin request and will not work if e.g. a login cookie is required on the remote side or not all requests should come from the same IP.

Answer (score 3):

Opera has not implemented CORS yet. It is actively worked on but we do not have a release date yet.

**Update 2012-07-26**:  As of today and since the release of Opera 12. Opera has a stable [implementation of CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors). Note that Opera Mini is not yet implementing CORS.

Comment: any updates on this? I tried finding a roadmap on opera.com, or any other documents mentioning CORS, but came up empty handed.

Comment: @nikc The way we declare what we support is highlighted in [Web specifications support in Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/). Be careful though because for example, as of today, [2.8](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/) there will be build numbers beside the features. Some are pre-announced because they are already in the pipe the [core integration point](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/) is important to check too. As you can see it is not done yet for CORS.

Comment: Downvoting just because this answer is out of date and no longer correct.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks for reminding me :p I'm working for Opera.

Answer (score 3):

[The latest version of Opera's rendering engine, Presto 2.10, now supports CORS.](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/#m210-236)

> - Enabled Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for XMLHttpRequest. ***(Presto/2.10.232)***

But a desktop version of Opera has not yet been released with this version of the rendering engine. So far only one version of Opera seems to have the CORS support, Mobile 12.

Here's an excerpt from the February 27, 2012 update to their ["Web specifications support in Opera products"](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/) page:

```
Miscellaneous

Item | D11.60 | D11.50 | SDK 3.2 | SDK3.1 | M12 | M11.5 | M11.1 | M11 | Mini6.5
-----+--------+--------+---------+--------+-----+-------+-------+-----+--------
CORS | No     | No     | No      | No     | Yes | No    | No    | No  | No
```

**D**=desktop **SDK**=device SDK **M**=mobile **Mini**=Mini (-:

And now that table has been updated again since version 12 for the desktop has been released finally with CORS support:

```
Item | D12.00 | D11.60 | D11.50 | SDK 3.2 | SDK3.1 | M12 | M11.5 | M11.1 | M11 | Mini6.5
-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+-----+-------+-------+-----+--------
CORS | Yes    | No     | No     | Yes     | Yes    | No  | Yes   | No    | No  | No
```