# can't manage to do cross-domain xmlhttprequest in userjs (injected script) in latest (stable 12 and beta v. 1497) opera, is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, opera, userscripts

The thing is that it works when script is on a page, that is normally fetched from the net, but when code lies in userscript, that is as a part of plugin, suddenly it forgets that there is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header and stops responding to cross domain requests.

Here is some code that illustrates this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include     *nasa.gov*
// ==/UserScript==

var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  alert('state changed: ' + this.readyState + "\nstatus: " + this.status);
};
xhr.onload = function(){
  alert('document loaded');
};
xhr.open('GET','http://apod.nasa.gov');
xhr.send(null);
```

I've chosen apod site since it has not got b&w of modern websites, so there is no need to filter events.

And in this state it works, ok but when I point this url to my server which accepts call from every site, it ignores allow-origin header...

Ok, is it a bug, or I'm doing something wrong here ? Maybe some option on request object to 'assure' it that it is ok to go there ?. I don't know like `xhr.allowcrossdomainaccess = true` or whatever ?

Comment: On which page (exact url) did you try this?

Comment: http://apod.nasa.gov/ - this is userscript, so i chose a page that is stripped of possibly all the features that trigger js events, since thet it would make my example harder.

Comment: Hm, works like a charm to execute your script (in Opera's console) at http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html

Comment: Um, wait, do you say that this script works but not when you try to get a page from your server? Please show us the script that does *not* work - inclunding the url to your server.

Comment: Ok, I found it... seems that userjs files can't do cross site request, Period. The solution is to use bacground.js in your extension and make userjs talk to it... http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-extension-code-examples/ -> example 4 , i'm going to try it now.

Comment: You've got no extension, you have an ordinary userscript. Show us the url you want to retrieve information from when beeing located at apod.nasa.gov, and we'll tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I meant userscript as part of extension, that the files whicha are in `includes` folder. Now I see it is called 'injected script' but it is virtually thesame as userscript/greasemonkey etc.. so maybe I confused some things there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You've already figured this out - but just to give this question a proper Answer..)

Injected scripts run in the page with (mostly) normal security privileges - same as page scripts do. Hence, you won't typically be able to do cross-domain requests from injected scripts.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614760/163549 for CORS implementation status in Opera.